# Can't install Kubernetes on Vagrant

Tags: docker, vagrant, virtualbox, kubernetes

Use this guide to install Kubernetes on Vagrant cluster:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/

At `(2/4) Initializing your master`, there came some errors:

```
[root@localhost ~]# kubeadm init
[kubeadm] WARNING: kubeadm is in beta, please do not use it for production clusters.
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.6.4
[init] Using Authorization mode: RBAC
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
    /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables contents are not set to 1
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can skip pre-flight checks with `--skip-preflight-checks`
```

I checked the `/proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables` file content, there is only one `0` in it.

At `(3/4) Installing a pod network`, I downloaded `kube-flannel` file:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml

And run `kubectl apply -f kube-flannel.yml`, got error:

```
[root@localhost ~]# kubectl apply -f kube-flannel.yml
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Until here, I don't know how to goon.

My `Vagrantfile`:

```
  # Master Server
  config.vm.define "master", primary: true do |master|
    master.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.200"
    master.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 1234, id: 'ssh'
  end
```

Comment: Is that the full `Vagrantfile` that someone could use to reproduce the issue? Specifically, it is not clear what base image you are using. Also, what other commands were run after `kubeadm init`? If you could clarify this in your question so it is easier to reproduce that would be helpful.

Comment: Did you successfully install master using `kubeadm init` ? Did you export the location on the KUBECONFIG file as specified in the doc you mentioned?

Comment: @AndyShinn @chaitukopparthi `kubeadm init` was okay. It generated a token, too. But now the problem is that can't join to master host from nodes hosts. I created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44132179/cant-join-kubernetes-master-from-nodes-hosts-by-vagrant

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In order to set `/proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables` by editing `/etc/sysctl.conf`. There you can add [1]

```
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1
```

Then execute

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

And the changes will be applied. With this the pre-flight check should pass.

---

[1]  http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Net.bridge.bridge-nf-call_and_sysctl.conf

Answer (score 25):

### Update @2019/09/02

Sometimes `modprobe br_netfilter` is unreliable, you may need to redo it after relogin, so use the following instead when on a systemd sytem:

```sh
echo br_netfilter > /etc/modules-load.d/br_netfilter.conf
systemctl restart systemd-modules-load.service
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-ip6tables
```

---

YES, the accepted answer is right, but I faced with

> cannot stat /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-ip6tables: No such file or directory

So I did

```
modprobe br_netfilter

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-ip6tables
sudo sysctl -p
```

Then solved.

Comment: you save my life, it appear the k8s need this file after some crash issues happend.

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu 16.04 I just had to:

```
modprobe br_netfilter
```

Default value in `/proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables` is already `1`.

Then I added `br_netfilter` to `/etc/modules` to load the module automatically on next boot.

Comment: Had to do this on Ubuntu 22.04 too (AWS).

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in K8s docs - [Installing kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#letting-iptables-see-bridged-traffic) under the **Letting iptables see bridged traffic** section:

> Make sure that the `br_netfilter` module is loaded. This can be done
> by running `lsmod | grep br_netfilter`. 
> To load it explicitly call
> `sudo modprobe br_netfilter`.
>
> As a requirement for your Linux Node's iptables to correctly see
> bridged traffic, you should ensure
> `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables` is set to 1 in your sysctl
> config, e.g.

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/k8s.conf
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1
EOF
sudo sysctl --system
```

---

Regardng the preflight erros - you can see in [Kubeadm Implementation details](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/implementation-details/#preflight-checks) under the **preflight-checks**:

> Kubeadm executes a set of preflight checks before starting the init,
> with the aim to verify preconditions and avoid common cluster startup
> problems..

The following missing configurations will produce errors:

```
.
.
if /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables file does not exist/does not contain 1

if advertise address is ipv6 and /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-ip6tables does not exist/does not contain 1.

if swap is on
.
.
```

Answer (score 2):

The one-liner way:

```
sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1
```