# Got only one node after install Kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, vagrant, kubernetes, cluster-computing

Followed official guide to install Kubernetes cluster with `kubeadm` on Vagrant.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/

- master
- node1
- node2

## Master

```
# kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.33.200

# sudo cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/
# sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/admin.conf
# export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/admin.conf

# wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
# kubectl apply -f kube-flannel.yaml
```

## Node1 and Node2

```
# kubeadm join --token <token> 192.168.33.200:6443
...
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"

Node join complete:
* Certificate signing request sent to master and response
  received.
* Kubelet informed of new secure connection details.

Run 'kubectl get nodes' on the master to see this machine join.
```

Until now all success.

But when check `kubectl get nodes` on master host, retunes only one node:

```
# kubectl get nodes
NAME                    STATUS    AGE       VERSION
localhost.localdomain   Ready     25m       v1.6.4
```

Sometimes, it retunes:

```
# kubectl get nodes
Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

---

## Edit

Add `hostname` to all the hosts.

Then check `kubectl get nodes` again from master:

```
[root@master ~]# kubectl get nodes
NAME                    STATUS    AGE       VERSION
localhost.localdomain   Ready     4h        v1.6.4
master                  Ready     12m       v1.6.4
```

Just added a new current host name.

Comment: It's best to add all the nodes (including master) into `/etc/hosts`

Comment: @lang2 I did that. Then, just added a new master name as I edited the question at bottom.